# kotlin Assign the result of this transformation to a variables

Tags: collections, kotlin, iterator

Hi I am working with the next code:

```
private fun getAttributesMap(navMenu: NavItem?): AttributesMap {
        var attributesString = navMenu?.attributes
        val attributesMap = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
        attributesString?.lines()?.map {
            val pair = it.split("=")
            if (pair?.size == 2) {
                attributesMap.put(pair[0], pair[1])
            }
        }
        return AttributesMap(attributesMap)
    }
```

But according with the documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html

I should be able to assign the result of this transformation to attributesMap. Any clues about how it will be with the kotlin .map approach?

Thanks!!

Comment: Indeed - using `.map` to execute side effects is discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `map` and `filter` will work:

```
val attributesMap = attributesString.lines()
    .map { it.split("=") }
    .filter { it.size == 2 } //filter all with more or less elements
    .map { it[0] to it[1] } //convert to Pair
    .toMap() //convert to Map
```

Comment: FWIW I think a slightly less verbose option is to replace the last two lines with `.associate { it[0] to it[1] }`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thank you for the hint. Until today the function was not known to me.